# Is it practicable to make third-party frameworks to static frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

My app depends on many static frameworks. And these frameworks are imported by CocoaPods. All frameworks also depend on some third-party frameworks, such as: AFNetWorking. Is it practicable to make third-party frameworks to static frameworks. And what's the strengths and weaknesses of it.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple answer to this question. It depends on the framework. Some tolerate being made static very easily and some have build steps that assume they're a dynamic framework. You will need to just try. You should expect this to be fairly time consuming with a lot of trial and error. There is no single, simple answer to reworking build processes of 3rdparty frameworks.

That said, you cannot easily make the bottom dependency (AFNetworking) static if any of its including frameworks are dynamic. In practice, this strongly limits how much you can make static.